# Cumulative sum in numpy with a lag

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to do a cumulative sum on a numpy array but with the data lagged by 1. I've managed to find a solution using pandas, but speed is an issue as my code is being run over many simulations and I would prefer to use numpy for broadcasting. Example is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#example of data structure
lim = np.linspace(start=1.5e3, stop=42e3, num=2)
xs = np.linspace(start=1e3, stop=2200, num=2)
aad = np.linspace(start=1000, stop = 1000, num=2)

clm_sev = np.array((1500,1700,2500,1500))[:,np.newaxis]
xol_loss = np.clip(a=clm_sev - xs, a_min=0, a_max=lim)

#steps to improve
cum_sum_0 = pd.DataFrame(xol_loss).shift(1).cumsum().fillna(0).to_numpy()
rem_aad_0 = np.maximum(aad-cum_sum_0,0)    
loss_in_aad = np.minimum(xol_loss,rem_aad_0)
loss_after_aad = np.maximum(xol_loss-loss_in_aad,0)
```

So `cum_sum_0` is where I current do the cumulative sum. as you can see the process is convoluted, I first convert the array to a dataframe, then shift (lag) the dataframe by 1, calculate the cumulative sum then convert it back to an array so I can continue with my calcs. Does anyone have a better (faster) way to repeat that line, or improve the lines following the code?

Comment: `cum_sum_0 = cum_sum_0[1:]` gives you a shifted array.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `np.array cum_sum_0` with `np.zeros_like` to fill the first row with zeroes.  Then use the slice indexing to perform the lag.

```
cum_sum_0 = np.zeros_like( xol_loss )
cum_sum_0[ 1:] = xol_loss[ :-1 ].cumsum( axis = 0 )

cum_sum_0
# array([[   0.,    0.],
#        [ 500.,    0.],
#        [1200.,    0.],
#        [2700.,  300.]])
```